# I can't get the second rewrite rule to work in my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working locally on Windows 7 with wamp server (v2.5). I have one working rewrite rule for the main front controller in my project, like this:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

It successfully strips .php from the queries. From this main front controller *index.php* I have a link to another front controller named *theme.php*, where I use menu links w/o the.php file extension, like this:

```
theme/regions
```

in stead of

```
theme.php/regions
```

For that to work I need to add a second rewrite rule to add the php exension, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^theme($|/$)      theme.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

The only thing I get is a 404 page though :-(.

I would be very grateful for some hints on how to go about this.

Comment: Most likely this is simply a question of order? The first rule matches nearly always. So when should the second one match? In general, see if you can activate rewrite logging. It shows you exactly what is going on inside your rewriting engine.

Comment: Is the line in question above the first rule?

Comment: Now it is, but it still is not working ... 404

Comment: Rewrite logging would be a great help.. I cannot find how to turn that on though... I keep trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your theme rule **before** the general route to `index.php`. And you need to reference what comes after the `/theme/` so something like:

```
RewriteRule ^theme(/?.*)$ theme.php$1 [L]
```

Additionally, this rule won't work if you have `Multiviews` turned on, but, this is actually something that's perfectly suited for `Multiviews` anyways, so you could just try turning that on instead of using a rule to rewrite `theme`:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time... does multiviews mean that I need to first add the complete links in my menus, like 'theme.php/regions' in stead of 'theme/regions' ?

Comment: @ToJo_195 no, you can add `/theme/regions` and multiviews will recognize that there is a `/theme.php` file and automatically change the request to `/theme.php/regions`.

Comment: Thanks again, your rewrite rule gives the wanted result. I echo $_SERVER('PHP_SELF') and now I can see that the rewritten query is correct, but I still get 404 though, for some reason...I keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `RewriteRule` works independently of the others and should be placed above the others in your question.

In addition, the format is wrong - you don't need to capture or append anything.

```
RewriteRule ^theme/?$ theme.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I moved it to the first position, using the same rewrite conditions, same result though.